# I'm having problems with validation in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am new to PHP, I had a problem in registering a user in Database. I want to first validate the form using javascript then form action to perform which will redirect it to another page containing PHP code and SQL queries. But the problem is it only validates Username and Email. No other field is checked by javascript.
**Register.php**

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
function initthis() {
    document.getElementById("signup").disabled = true;
}

function dis_enable_submit() {
    if (document.getElementById("t&d").checked == 1) {
        document.getElementById("signup").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("signup").className = "enabled";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("signup").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("signup").className = "disabled";

    }
}
window.onload = initthis;

function validateForm() {
    var a = document.forms["register"]["duser"].value;
    var b = document.forms["register"]["demail"].value;
    var c = document.forms["register"]["dcemail"].value;
    var d = document.forms["register"]["dpwd"].value;
    var e = document.forms["register"]["dcpwd"].value;

    if (a == null || a == "") {
        document.getElementById("duser").style.background = "#FDFCDC";
        return false;
    }

    var atpos = b.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = b.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= b.length) {
        document.getElementById("demail").style.background = "#FDFCDC";
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("tick").src = "images/tick.gif";
    }
    if (c == null || c == "") {
        document.getElementById("dcemail").style.background = "#FDFCDC";
        alert("Email doesn't match");
        return false;
    }

    if (c != b) {
        alert("Email doesn't match");
        return false;
    }

    if (d == null || d == "") {
        document.getElementById("dpwd").style.background = "#FDFCDC";
        return false;
    }

    if (e == null || e == "") {
        document.getElementById("dcpwd").style.background = "#FDFCDC";
        alert("Password doesn't match");
        return false;
    }


    if (e != d) {
        alert("Password doesn't match");
        return false;
    }


}
```

This is FORM which is to be validate

```
<form name="register" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post" action="getdata.php">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="background:url('images/register.jpg') no-repeat; height:50px; width: 350px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>*Username:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="duser" id="duser" value="" type="text" spellcheck="false" size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>*Email:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="demail" id="demail" value="" type="text" size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>*Confirm Email:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="dcemail" id="dcemail" value="" type="text" size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>*Password:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="dpwd" id="dpwd" value="" type="password" size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>*Confirm Password:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="dcpwd" id="dcpwd" value="" type="password" size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>*Gender:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="1">Male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="0">Female</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Birthday:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="bday" id="bday" type="date" size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="middle">
                <input id="signup" class="button" type="submit" value="Sign Up" style="font-size:15px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

getdata.php

```
<?php
$_POST[duser];
$_POST[demail];
$_POST[dpwd];
$_POST[gender];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","MyDB");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Users (UserName, Email, Password, Gender)
VALUES ('$_POST[duser]', '$_POST[demail]','$_POST[dpwd]',$_POST[gender] )");

mysqli_close($con);


header("Location: successful.php");
exit();

?>
```

Comment: You'll be a lot better off validating the form on the server side with PHP. Javascript validation can be bypassed very easily by anyone by disabling Javascript in their browser.

Comment: I want validation process just as google, where validation is done at the time when we leave the input field. Can u suggest something for that?

Comment: @ChrisWhite validating on the server side should always be done but it doesn't mean you shouldn't also validate on the client side, in the majority of cases this will reduce the number requests to the server.

Comment: They do that with javascript but they also do it in the backend (server side) because of the reasone mentioned by @ChrisWhite

Comment: if using pure javascript have a look at [**`onblur()`**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown then can you tell me which validation process is used by google?

Comment: @Rahul You could have at-least formatted your code before posting :) Also, once your question is posted, please go through it again to see if everything is displayed properly. In this case the first 4 lines of your HTML wasn't even displayed because of code formatting issues :(

Comment: This post was 2 times edited by others, So I don't think now it has any formatting issues :)

Answer (score 1):

FYI: Be more descriptive when asking for help or simply explain what you want to do, you will get a rapid response as opposed to copying the code from the internet and wonder why it's not working. I see you have dis_enable_submit() function, but I can't see where you calling it. You can also make use of jsfiddle.net/‎ if you have such long files.

Comment: Here I am calling dis_enable_submit() function
`<tr>
<td>
<input id="t&d" type="checkbox" value="0" tabindex="3" onclick="dis_enable_submit();"/><span> I agree all </span><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a>
</td>
</tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code.

```
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script>
            $.validator.setDefaults({
            submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
         });

         $().ready(function() {
             // validate the comment form when it is submitted
             $("#commentForm").validate();

         });
        </script>

    </head>



    <form id="commentForm" class="formular" method="post" action="" style="width:600px">
                <p class="name">
                    <input value="" class="text-input" type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" required />
                    <label for="fullname">Name</label>
                </p>
                <p class="email">
                    <input value="" class="text-input" type="text" name="email" id="email" required />
                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                </p>
                <p class="web">
                    <input type="text" name="web" id="web" />
                    <label for="web">Website</label>
                </p>
                <p class="text">
                    <textarea name="text" class="text-input" id="comment" required></textarea>
                </p>
                <p class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
                </p>
            </form>
```

Comment: I want to use javascript as I don't know about JQuery.

Comment: Jquery is a JavaScript library and you can do so much stuff with it.  There are a lot of examples online and this is where i found this

Answer (score 0):

It is not running your `validateForm()` function because you have not called that function anywhere.

Suggestion based on existing code:

```
<input onclick="return validateform()" id="signup" class="button" type="submit" value="Sign Up" style="font-size:15px;" />
```

This should run the validation when you press the button and only complete the SUBMIT if that function returns TRUE.

So you will also have to add a `return true;` to the end of the function so if it passes all the tests i.e. does not do a `return false;` it will `return true`, which is not the default.

Comment: I had called valdateForm() function here
`<form name="register" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post" action="getdata.php">`

Comment: Woops, I missed that. Sorry.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Most of us did, it didn't appear initially because of code block formatting issues :)